# Reverse engineer diskimage path from Volume name?

Tags: mac-osx, mount, files

I have a sparse-image diskimage that is mounted on my system but I can't find the 
original file.

Is there a way to reverse engineer the location of the diskimage on file from the mount point (e.g /Volume/my-sparse-image) using command line tools?

I've tried diskutil and mount with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to open Disk Utility as it should show the Disk Image on the left hand side and the volume it mounted below it.

Alternatively if you run `hdiutil info` it will show the image path and mount point (along with other information) of all the disk images mounted on your computer.

Comment: I really want to use the command line because I'm working on a utility script for my coworkers.

`hdiutil info` without any other arguments is answer I needed.